# getting error on posting photo on facebook wall

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hi i have implement facebook graph api in objective c and getting errors like this

```
dictionary , {
    error =     {
        code = 190;
        message = "Malformed access token AAAGKSrZBYyhABALuirFQZAdHsWE5hqMvr8f7RoVqPSW7Rvtkh1T98gBcT93C5htSLt8XM8WvTF8JRZBI6HnjkEZAlLhc9EgQEecFZC5jHwQZDZD&expires_in=5159421";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
}
2013-01-10 20:33:06.665 FBFun[3325:11303] Photo id is: (null)
2013-01-10 20:33:20.448 FBFun[3325:11303] Got Facebook Photo: {"error":{"message":"(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: (null)","type":"OAuthException","code":803}}
```

every thing working file i can get all my profile information from facebook but not able to post photo on facebook wall also i have implemented these tutorial from this site 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app
kindly tell me if you have any idea how to post photo

Comment: You follow all necessary instruction that tell in this link?

Comment: Also share your code of sending image via Graph API...